# python-requests %2F characters

Tags: python-requests

I am building a request containing a list of parameters, this is a list of endpoints that is read from a file. All these containing "/" characters.

First the file is read as:

```
pointRef = []
with open("myfolder/" + scope, 'r') as f:
for line in f:
    pointRef.append(line.strip())
```

then passing

```
params = {'endDate': endDate, 'startDate': startDate, 'pointRef': pointRef}
```

and executing

```
r = requests.get(url=url_ranged_multiple, headers=headers, params=params)
```

and this gives error (I tried other requests by hand and they work), but I noticed that the final url request that is composed by "request.get" contains the "%2F" character instead of "/"

I wonder if this is the problem how can I correct it.
Many thanks in advance